# iOS File Association

Tags: ios, ios4

I've set up file association in my iOS application for KML and KMZ files.

I've the app is not opened, then selecting "Open With APPNAME" from Safari will work.
If the app is already open, however, then all it does it make the app prominent.

I've implemented both `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`
and
 `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Neither are being called.

Any hints as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result: The test device was using an earlier OS version (iOS 4.0) than my other devices (iOS 4.3.5, iOS 5.0b7). Prior to iOS4.2, a different method was used to handle opening via file association.